# Is Simple.OData.Client supposed to work with OData V4?

Tags: client, odata

I'm trying to get Simple.OData.Client to consume a OData V4 service,but doesn't work.

Hence my question: Is Simple.OData.Client supposed to work with OData V4?

Also,I'm using it in a PCL. Could this be the problem?

Regards,

Avrohom

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on full support of OData v4. I am done with read part, implementing support for updates. An early beta is expected mid-September with final version around October 1st.

UPDATE: Simple.OData.Client 4.0 RC candidate is available that supports both JSON payload and OData V4 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Simple.OData.Client [Is OData V4 supported](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/32), OData V4 not fully supported. And one big problem is that they cannot support JSON format while JSON is OData V4 standard. According to their word, you have to wait couple of months for V4 support. You can also choose OData Client Code Generator if it can work for you. [tutorial for OData client code gen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/12/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx)